# Co - generator based lib for node.js. How i can run parallel tasks?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, express

I have tried generator based async lib co ([GitHub](https://github.com/visionmedia/co)) for node.js

Here is the code. I use co-express and co-wait.

As you can see client wait 10 seconds before he get response.
My problem is - if i try to run multiple requests to this url and all functions will block next calls.

How i can run multiple calls to this url in parallel?
localhost:8000/test

```
var fs = require('fs');
var co = require('co');
var express = require('express');
var wrapper = require('co-express');
var app = wrapper(express());
var wait = require('co-wait');

app.get('/test', function* (req, res, next) {
    yield waitAndAnswer(res)
});

function* waitAndAnswer (res) {
  yield wait(10000);
  res.send('Done: ' + Date.now());
}

app.listen(8000);
```

Comment: if you're making calls via your browser, then its a browser thing. if you call it via curl or something, it should be fine.

Comment: Jonathan, Thank you. You're right. I have tried by curl and different browsers - it's work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake, when tried to call this url by single browser. Looks like it standard behavior of browsers, so this code work as expected. Jonathan Ong have answered my question.

> if you're making calls via your browser, then its a browser thing. if you call it via curl or something, it should be fine. – Jonathan Ong